# Iterating array, does not perform as expected

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have been working on getting this to work correct. I had a little help from you guys earlier, with it. But now it is not performing as expected anymore.

As you can see I am working out from these to arrays. Now I want it to add a point to the `$prize` array for every iteration. 
But only doing so if the stats arrays, has a similar or greater value. 
Now I expected it to when it hit the 0 value in array `$stats`, that it would just skip, and then continue to next in the array, or start over. 
Instead, it seems like added the value randomly to **"Pig-/Slethvar"** were I expected it to add it instead to **"Torsk"**

```
$prize = [
    "Torsk" => 0,
    "Rødspætte" => 0,
    "Mørksej" => 0,
    "Skrubbe" => 0,
    "Lubbe/Lyssej" => 0,
    "Ising" => 0,
    "Lange" => 0,
    "Makrel" => 0,
    "Hornfisk" => 0,
    "Pig-/Slethvar" => 0,
    "Havkat" => 0,
    "Laks/Havørred" => 0,
];

$stats = [
    "Torsk" => 5,
    "Rødspætte" => 5,
    "Mørksej" => 5,
    "Skrubbe" => 5,
    "Lubbe/Lyssej" => 5,
    "Ising" => 5,
    "Lange" => 5,
    "Makrel" => 5,
    "Hornfisk" => 5,
    "Pig-/Slethvar" => 5,
    "Havkat" => 5,
    "Laks/Havørred" => 0,
];

$points = 21;


for ($i = 0; $i < count($prize); ++$i) {

    foreach ($prize as $key => $value) {

       if (array_sum($prize) == $points) {
          break 2;
        }
      elseif ($stats[$key] > $prize[$key]) {
      $prize[$key]++;
        }
      elseif ($stats[$key] < $prize[$key]) {
        continue;
        }
    }
}  

foreach ($prize as $key => $value) {

    $prize_array[] = ['art' => $key, 'antal' => $value];   

}
echo json_encode($prize_array);
```

EDITED as requested:

I end up with array of the following:

> ```
> "Torsk" => 2,
> "Rødspætte" => 2,
> "Mørksej" => 2,
> "Skrubbe" => 2,
> "Lubbe/Lyssej" => 2,
> "Ising" => 2,
> "Lange" => 2,
> "Makrel" => 2,
> "Hornfisk" => 2,
> "Pig-/Slethvar" => 2,
> "Havkat" => 1,
> "Laks/Havørred" => 0
> ```

Where as I expected the following instead:

```
"Torsk" => 3,
"Rødspætte" => 2,
"Mørksej" => 2,
"Skrubbe" => 2,
"Lubbe/Lyssej" => 2,
"Ising" => 2,
"Lange" => 2,
"Makrel" => 2,
"Hornfisk" => 2,
"Pig-/Slethvar" => 1,
"Havkat" => 1,
"Laks/Havørred" => 0
```

Comment: Describe the result you want to achieve, do not explain the code you wrote. The code is too convoluted to be useful, anyway.

Comment: @axiac Done, I hope that shows what I mean.

Comment: Looking at the sample data provided, I can't figure how `Torsk` is expected to have the value of 3, they all seem to have the same `stats` and `prize` value

Comment: What is the rule of distributing the points? The result you get matches the description you put in the question. The expected result doesn't match it.

Comment: @WilliamPerron Actually if "Laks/Havørred" if stats was above 0, then it would go there in $prize as well. But instead it was assigned to "Pig-/Slethvar" => 2

Comment: @Lasser then you should edit your sample data to represent this use case, currently `Laks/Havørred` has a value of 0 in both array, as far as I can tell with the provided data, the algorith is doing what it is supposed to with the provided data set

Comment: @WilliamPerron that is exactly my issue, because when the iteration meets the 0 value in $stats, it should skip that iteration, and then move on to next key and value ind the array. That is what I am trying to get it to do.

Comment: @Lasser I understand that, however in your sample data, the only element of `$stats` to have a value of `0` is `Laks/Havørred` which gets skipped as expected

Comment: @WilliamPerron yes as it should.
But in my ignorance I believed that the iterations would be sequential. So that then because `Laks/Havørred` is skipped, then it would just go to the next in the array being `Torsk` as it resets. But I just read the internal pointer is not used as of PHP v.7, so instead it adds the value to
`Pig-/Slethvar`.  
I expected the foreach to handle the array one by one, in the order that it is setup. And that it my issue, that it does not do that.